# Possible to use Google Channels API with RoboVM (for iOS)?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api, robovm

Is it possible to combine RoboVM code with Goole Channels API using this client:

[Java AppEngine Channel Client](https://github.com/gvsumasl/jacc)

```
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible and works!!